# Consolidate wealth management / advisors or use multiple?

Tags: united-kingdom, financial-advisor, bond-funds

About 10 years ago, my parents organised a joint account with a financial advisor for me and my sisters, and it was seeded with a lump sum that we all inherited. The advisor is a large "wealth/investment" firm which has about doubled the size of the account. Whilst I have access to an advisor in that firm, they wouldn't usually have let us have an account, it's only because we pooled together as a family that we were allowed - so I feel awkward going to them for financial advice.

Recently (last week or so), we gained access to a separate fund managed by a separate investement company. This is a life assured contract that will close when both my grandmother and father pass away. My grandma passed away several years ago, but hopefully my dad has a few years left in him! He's approaching 70. There is a tax benefit such that if I withdraw less than 5% each year then no extra taxes apply, anything over counts as income tax.

As I said, the fund is managed by a separate company. It would seem sensible to me that I start withdrawing / moving money over to the first fund so that I can keep the 5%pa tax benefit, but reduce complexity of having to monitor my finances. If I don't and my dad passes away (or I withdraw it all for e.g. a mortgage) then I could be taxed quite heavily.

My dad suggested that it might be better to keep the funds separate, for diversity. My understanding is that the first fund is already diverse - they manage lots of little investments/stock so we don't lose everything on one bad decision anyway.

My options seem to be:

- Keep the two separate funds, and take a tax hit when it closes
- Slowly consolidate them into one fund
- Slowly move the new fund to a different fund without the same tax hit
- ??

This is in the UK, and whilst both funds are "joint accounts" with my siblings, I am able to make independent decisions. We are on good terms and would also be willing to continue pooling money in order to continue working with financial advisors - although the value of both pots is now approaching £150k so we can probably have completely separate accounts now if thats beneficial.

Comment: With these 5% "investment bond" things, you can normally roll up unused withdrawals and take them out later.  For example, if you withdrew nothing for 20 years, you could take out 100% in one go.  Note that these are % of the original amount, not including any growth.  It's also not really "tax free", more "tax deferred" as the 5%s are just a return of the original capital.